# Finding $\int\frac{\sin^4 x+\cos^4 x}{\sin^3 x+\cos^3 x}dx$

Tags: integration

> Find
>   $$\int\frac{\sin^4 x+\cos^4 x}{\sin^3 x+\cos^3 x}dx$$

What I tried:

$$\sin^4(x)+\cos^4(x)=(\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x)^2-2\sin^2 x\cos^2 x=1-2\sin^2 x\cos^2 x$$

and $$\sin^3 x+\cos^3 x=(\sin x+\cos x)(1-\sin x\cos x)$$

so
$$\int\frac{1-\sin^2 x\cos^2 x}{(\sin x+\cos x)(1-\sin x\cos x)}dx-\int\frac{\sin^2 x\cos^2 x}{(\sin x+\cos x)(1-\sin x\cos x)}dx$$

How do I solve it? Help me, please.

Comment: notice that $-2\sin^{2} x \cos^{2} x = \frac{-\sin ^{2}  {2x}}{2}$

Comment: Try the tan-half angle substitution

Comment: $$(a^3+b^3)(a+b)=a^4+b^4+ab(a^2+b^2)$$

We have $\dfrac{\sin^4x+\cos^4x}{\sin^3x+\cos^3x}=\sin x+\cos x-\dfrac{\sin x\cos x}{\sin^3x+\cos^3x}$

Answer (score 2):

A brutal way is just to enforce the substitution $x=2\arctan t$, leading to
$$ \int\frac{\sin x\cos x}{\sin^3 x+\cos^3 x}\,dx=2\int\frac{\frac{2t(1-t^2)}{(1+t^2)^3}}{\frac{(2t)^3}{(1+t^2)^3}+\frac{(1-t^2)^3}{(1+t^2)^3}}\,dt=\int\frac{4t(1-t^2)}{(2t)^3+(1-t^2)^3}\,dt $$
an ugly integral, but perfectly solvable by partial fraction decomposition. The roots of $(2t)^3+(1-t^2)^3$ can be found by solving the quadratic equations given by 
$$\frac{1-t^2}{2t}\in\left\{-1,\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2},\frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right\}.$$